# How to have normal notifications over full screen applications in Gnome 3?

Tags: gnome, gnome3, notifications, fullscreen

In my workflow I use applications in fullscreen mode most of the time. The only serious drawnback I have in that is the way Gnome 3 handles desktop notifications, I can't get any normal notification, only when I'm switching from one application to another in rare times. Gnome 3 notifications only show them over fullscreen windows when the notification is urgent, but none are.

Is there a way to toggle normal notifications to show up over fullscreen?

Comment: I am looking for the same thing; in the meantime note that you can use `super-M` to show up notification tray

Comment: @CédricVanRompay I've found a [gnome-extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1610/fullscreen-notifications/) that actually solves the problem for me :)

Answer (score 8):

Does this Gnome extension solve the problem?

[Fullscreen Notifications](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1610/fullscreen-notifications/)

(say thanks to [them](https://github.com/soal/gnome-shell-extension-fullscreen-notifications) :)

Comment: not working in my case (ubuntu 21.04)

Comment: Can confirm this works for me on Debian 11 using GNOME 3.38.6!